# Give a domain for which the quantified statement is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let P(x) be the predicate "x is a registered voter."
a. Give a  domain for which the quantified statement "$\forall x\; P(x)$" is true.
b. Give a  domain for which the quantified statement "$\forall x$ ~$P(x)$" is true.
c. Give a domain for which neither quantified statement "$\forall x\; P(x)$" nor "$\forall x$ ~$P(x)$" is true.
d. Using the domains given above for a-c, for which domains would the quantified statement "$\exists x \;|$ ~$P(x)$" be true. Explain why or why not for each domain a-c.

I really do not understand this stuff. For a. I put "All U.S. voters". For b. I put "All residents under 18 in Florida". For c. and d. I don't have a clue. I'm not even sure I did a and b correctly. Sorry about the symbols. I couldn't find how to plug those in.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for a and b are fine. You have exactly the right idea there. For c, you just need a group that contains both registered voters and people who are not registered voters. There are plenty of examples of that!

For d, the question is, which of the three groups of (a), (b), and (c) includes at least one person who is not a registered voter? This should not be hard to figure out as one of the groups was required to have only registered voters, while the other two were required to have non-voters in them.

Comment: So for C I could just say "All US citizens"? There's some that aren't registered and some that are.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok. Now for D. Would you read that statement as "there is an x and x is not a registered voter". I have trouble translating those symbols into an english statement.

Comment: These are groups of people, so $x$ is a person. I.e., "There is a person who is not a registered voter".